# SVM:Need numeric dependent variable for regression

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
scorer<-function(points){
        points["scores"] <- as.vector((points$X-5)^2+(points$Y-5)^2-9)
        points["class"]<-(as.vector(  points$scores<0 ))
        points
}
dt<-scorer(data.frame(X=c(0,1,5,20,5,3,9,3,5,5),Y=c(0,9,9,0,-18,3,4,5,7,4)))
```

Then i am trying to predict the last column (class) using SVM

```
library(e1071)
model <- svm(class ~ . , dt)
predictedClass <- predict(model, dt)
```

but it complains with:

```
Error in svm.default(x, y, scale = scale, ..., na.action = na.action) : 
  Need numeric dependent variable for regression.
```

Comment: Try to specify that you wish a classification rather than regression: `model <- svm(class ~ . , dt, type = "C")`.

Answer (score 4):

The **advice** from [nya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5967807/nya) really works.

Please, have a look `type` parameter description

> svm can be used as a classification machine, as a regression machine, or for
>   novelty detection. Depending on whether y is a factor or not, the default setting
>   for type is **C-classification** or **eps-regression** ... [page 50](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

With your dataset you can make classification using svm method.

But if you want absolutely to make regression, try to transform your variable "class" in numeric form which can take value 1 for negative score and 0 for positif score.

```
function(points) {

points["scores"] <- as.vector((points$X-5)^2+(points$Y-5)^2-9)
                   points["class"]<-as.vector(  ifelse(points$scores<0 ,1,0))
                   points
                 }
dt<-scorer(data.frame(X=c(0,1,`enter code here`5,20,5,3,9,3,5,5),Y=c(0,9,9,0,-18,3,4,5,7,4)))
svm(class~.,dt)
```

Comment: Please read [the good answer guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and format your code.